# If else condition, return value

Tags: php

I'm searching in user profile if there's a string inside `appetit` with the word `demi`.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$profile = JUserHelper::getProfile($user->id);
$prixa = $profile->profile['appetit'];

if (strpos($prixa,'demi') !== false) {
    $prix=6;
} else {
    $prix=7;
}
```

Comment: could you check the value that returned from `$prixa ` it may be in uppercase or mixed or there is whitespace so try to use `tolower(trim($prixa))`

Comment: What are the values of `$prixa`? Can you provide some test case. We don't really know what is inside `$prixa`

Comment: $prixa is suppose to return the full string : "Repas demi portion" .. I'm searching inside this string, if there's the word "demi" then $prix=6 .. if there's no "demi" ... $prix=7

Comment: What's the framework you're working with? I don't recognize its syntax.

Comment: I'm using it with "RSform pro" to calculate a price, if user, when registered has chosen "Repas demi portion", the script checks the database in "appetit" holder, the price is 6$ .. if not, the price is 7$ .. any way making this script work? thanks everyone for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

seems to be working as expected. Below is a test case code I ran.

```
<?php
$prixa = 'emimore';
if (strpos($prixa,'demi') !== false) {
    $prix=6;
} else {
    $prix=7;
}
echo $prix;
```

?>